# How to pass get request through servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If I create a button form on edit it gave me null pointer. In the other hand if I use hyperlink there are no problem at all. But how am I able to pass values correctly? What I want to pass is the action=edit

```
public class WaterController extends HttpServlet {
...
    private static final String LIST_PIPES="WEB-INF/jsp/listPipess.jsp";
    private static final String INSERT_EDIT = "WEB-INF/jsp/pipe.jsp";
    private static final String EDIT_MODIFY = "WEB-INF/jsp/edit.jsp";
    private static final String DELETE = "WEB-INF/jsp/delete.jsp";
    private PipeD pipeD;
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String forward = null;
String action=request.getParameter("action");
if(action.equals("list")){
request.setAttribute("pipes", pipeD.getAllPipes());
forward = LIST_PIPES;
} else if(action.equals("insert")) {
forward=INSERT_EDIT;
} else if(action.equals("edit")) {
request.setAttribute("pipeId", request.getParameter("pipeId"));
request.setAttribute("pipeSerial", request.getParameter("pipeSerial"));
request.setAttribute("pipeType", request.getParameter("pipeType"));
request.setAttribute("pipePrice", request.getParameter("pipePrice"));
request.setAttribute("dateOrdered", request.getParameter("dateOrdered"));
forward=EDIT_MODIFY; 
} else if(action.equals("delete")) {...}
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

----------------------------------- In JSP (edit.jsp) ----------------

```
...
<form action="BookController?action=edit&id=${p.pipeId}&price=${p.pipePrice}" method="post">
<br/> Pipe Id: [READ]<input type="text" name="pipeId"  value='<c:out value="${p.pipeId}"/>' readonly="readonly"/><c:out value="${p.pipeId}"/>
<br/> Pipe Serial: [READ]<input type="text" name="pipeSerial"  value='<c:out value="${p.pipeSerial}"/>' readonly="readonly"/><c:out value="${p.pipeSerial}"/> 
<br/> Pipe Type: [READ]<input type="text" name="pipeType"  value='<c:out value="${p.pipetype}"/>' readonly="readonly"/><c:out value="${p.bookAuthor}"/>
<br/> Pipe Type: <input type="text" name="pipeType"  value='<c:out value="${p.pipeType}"/>' />
<br/> Date Ordered (mm/dd/yyyy) [READ]: <input type="text" name="dateOrdered"  value='<fmt:formatDate value="${p.dateOrdered}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>'readonly="readonly"/>
<br/><input type="submit" value="update"/><fmt:formatDate value="${p.dateOrdered}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
</form>
...
```

------------------listPipe.jsp-------

```
<td><form action="BookController?action=edit"><input type="submit" value="Edit"></form></td>
```

This line is where I want to redirect to the edit url. (when clicked immediately null pointer)

Error I got is java.lang.NullPointerException at  "if(action.equals("list")){"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the form submission if the method is `GET` type, then request parameters may not be passed to the server side.

Change the method type as `POST` or use a hidden field inside the `form` tag like below to pass the argument to the server side

```
<form action="BookController">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit">
<input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Comment: In the doPost I have
PipeD dao = new PipeD();
 dao.editPrice(request);

Comment: @Shang if you don't want to use post method, try using the hidden input element you will be able to receive the value in the server side

Comment: @Shang  It should work . are you getting null pointer for the same action value ?

Comment: Is it possible to pass value along with the method form? for example if I want to pass in value to the field as read only in the text box